# Which sensor can be used to measure depth in oil well

Tags: sensor

In an oil well and there is a need to insert an electronics circuit. Which sensor can be used to measure depth of that electronic circuit in well as it goes down the well (depth in meters)? The pressure and temperature are extreme down there as the depth is increased.

Comment: That sensor is probably attached to a cable, isn't it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller that was probaly too obvious :)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Transistor : No practical :)

Comment: @adeelasif so: cable attached or not?

Comment: I believe you should give some more information about the environment the sensor will be put in. Basically, what is an oil well? A cylindrical hole in the rock with gas, are there pipes around it (I guess not, otherwise you just need to count the number of pipe sections), is there... oil in it or you need to measure the depth before striking the oil? What pressure? What temperature? What kind of accessibility?

Comment: @adeelasif without any specification about your sensor, how it gets down the well, what accuracy you need, what "extreme pressure and temperature" actually means in numbers, I'm afraid your question will get closed as too vague.

Answer (score 5):

#### TLDR;

If you are using a Drilling Information System, get the bit-depth or hole depth from it (contact your integrator). If you don't have that, it becomes difficult based on the environment that the device operates in and is impossible to provide a solution without knowing *a lot* of dirty details.

---

I work in the oil field...

Hole depth and bit-depth are two different things. The hole depth is the maximum value that the bit has reached, the bit however can be shallower especially during things like reaming or back-drilling.

Because the wells are not (usually) filled  to the top, you can't just stick a pressure transducer in the hole to figure out what depth the bit is at. If you are drilling a purely vertical well this isn't too hard, the depth of the bit is equal to the number of stands times the stand length (usually measured to the drill-floor if you have the pipe in the slips). This doesn't account for stretch but is usually accurate enough.

This becomes a bigger issue if you are doing directional drilling, so figuring out where the bit actually is is much harder. Directional drilling can be pretty precise since the bit is steerable so they typically know where the bit is, there is software on the rig that can tell you the bit depth and horizontal location.

So really the best way to know what depth your sensor package is on is to look at the bit depth from the drilling information system (DIS). The DIS can tell you exactly (within a stand or so) how deep the bit is. Depending on the DIS integrator, they may be able to make this available to you as an output from the PLC.

Harder yet would be to get this information to a device that is down-hole. Some communication methods have been used, like using the mud pumps to transfer sonic pulses down the hole which can be picked up by the instrument. It's almost unheard of to actually run cable down the hole because the cables will break, get caught, or get twisted (until they break). Most down-hole electronics are battery powered.

That's not to say there aren't cable-driven electronics, usually this is used in a wireline system and are lowered down the hole, this only works well in vertical wells with casing already in place. I did a system that lowered a radioactive package 10,000 meters down sea-floor wells through seismic faults to image them. We ran this tool down using a wireline system with an embedded set of wires for tool communication (the tool was still battery powered). It did not measure depth directly, we did that by knowing how much cable we've spooled off the winch and then calculating the depth. This was on a ship so we had to make a huge piece of equipment to cancel out the wave motion...

So really doing this on the tool is extremely difficult, considering that the temps/pressures are high (like you said), but also if the hole is filled with things like mud (drilling mud, not dirt/water), gas, or other fluids.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest of doing this.
 First measure the oil depth by using any cable or tape. Then place your distance sensor above the oil level.
 Now if the oil level goes below you can subtract that distance from the actual depth or add the actual distance when oil level goes up. You can use ultrasonic distance sensors or laser distance sensor made by STM. VL53L1X.